# Top new user email

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I recently received an email titled: "Top new Parenting - Stack Exchange users for the week of Apr 11 2011‏"

However when I click through on the [link provided](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/parenting) I can't see any information about myself.

I did some head scratching and realised it was for the previous week. Clicking through on the [prev link](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/103/week/parenting/2011-04-10) link on the above page I appear on the league and on the right hand side as expected.

I think to be helpful the link in the email should point to the link which references myself automatically otherwise it's confusing.

Note: I only received this email 30 minutes ago, so it's not like an email that was sent last week. It was sent this week and should point to last week.

Comment: its said Apr 11, you need to click during that time or click previous week link - http://stackexchange.com/leagues/103/week/parenting/2011-04-10

Comment: @YOU - The current time is UTC 1:51. I received the email at UTC 1:00. Which means I received the email 'this week' not 'last week' so a new user will always need to click the prev week, thus my suggestion to have it automatically point to the correct week.

Comment: sorry, you're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice catch.

Clearly including a link to the most recent league rather than the league you actually placed in is... sub-optimal.

Going forward all such e-mails will instead use the correct historical league link.

Comment: Related bug: I received an email saying I'm on the top user list for ServerFault, but I'm not on *either* this week's or the previous week's list!