# Email to top new users has a link to a page that doesn't mention me

Tags: bug, new-users, email, reputation-leagues

I received the following email from StackExchange:

> Hello,
>
> Congratulations -- you are one of the top new Programming Puzzles & Code Golf - Stack Exchange users for the week of May 28 2012!
>
> https://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/codegolf/2012-05-28
>
> It's users like you who make the Programming Puzzles & Code Golf - Stack Exchange community worth visiting in the first place.

I clicked the link and found that I was not mentioned at all there. Eventually I clicked [next week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/88/week/codegolf/2012-06-04) and found my name there.

I checked this question, but it is marked as resolved and the problem I get is slightly different to the one described there:

- [Top new user email](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87785/top-new-user-email)

Just like the poster of that question, I would expect that clicking the link in the email would take me to a page where my name is mentioned.

Perhaps fixing that old bug introduced a new bug?

Comment: I see you has #13 on the [page you linked to](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/codegolf/2012-05-28) -- were you not there before?

Comment: No, I don't think I was there before. I used Ctrl+F to search for "Mark" and it didn't match at all. I don't know why I'm there now.